# Getting handshake errors on Grails frontend app which is talking to an API which has upgraded to TLS 1.1

Tags: tomcat, grails, tls1.2

The API server had earlier support for TLS version 1.0, and things were working fine. After it stopped support for 1.0, started getting these errors -

```
 Remote host closed connection during handshake
[08:50:16.593] [] ERROR UserProfileService         :200  - wslite.rest.RESTClientException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
[08:50:16.593] [] ERROR UserProfileService         :200  - null
```

On local setup, we run the Grails application directly on eclipse via the run-app command. To fix the TLS issue there, we added the `jvmArgs` config to application config file `BuildConfig.groovy`, and it worked -

```
grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false,jvmArgs: ['-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1']],
]
```

On sandbox server, we run the app by deploying a war file on tomcat server. We tried adding the same config change to the war attribute in the config file, but it did not work -

```
grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false,jvmArgs: ['-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1']],
]
```

We then also mentioned the same to tomcat config, but still no success. Here is the catalina log showing tomcat is taking the updated TLS config -

```
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/tomcat7-cpp2
May 31, 2018 8:49:18 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat7-cpp2/conf/logging.properties
May 31, 2018 8:49:18 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
May 31, 2018 8:49:18 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dhttps.protocol=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
May 31, 2018 8:49:18 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/tomcat7-cpp2/endorsed
May 31, 2018 8:49:18 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat7-cpp2
May 31, 2018 8:49:18 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat7-cpp2
May 31, 2018 8:49:18 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat7-cpp2/temp
May 31, 2018 8:49:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found o
n the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
```

We have not been able to confirm however, that the application is also reading the updated TLS config defined against the war attribute.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of the JVM is your server running? I assume you've checked that it supports TLS 1.2?

Comment: @Robert Yes we have Java 1.7 which supports TLS 1.1 and 1.2.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a typo in your Tomcat configuration where you specify `-Dhttps.protocol=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2`. The correct system variable is `https.protocols` (with the s).